# Emulate backend for testing and playing with Ajax?

Tags: html, ajax

I am front-end developer. I want to practice AJAX, but I don't want to write backend code. 
Is there any simulator, emulator for backend? I mean something like some kind of application simulate server www, in which I can set only constant resposones for my request.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used it, but JSFiddle I believe has this capability: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: Great, but I want to have this on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you run a local Web server you can just host static files at whatever endpoints your hitting.

Comment: Okay, but I don't want to install server.

Comment: AJAX is only made to work over HTTP connections, so you need to install some form server or something else that can server HTTP connections if you want to develop locally.  Otherwise you'll need to develop in a remote environment.  Running a simple and easy to set up Web server or using a development environment with an embedded server would be the way to go for a local environment, any possible workaround would end up far more complex.

Comment: You could also alternately create an entirely fake sandbox within JavaScript, but this will also be more complicated and more importantly less demonstrative of how the actual calls will behave.

Comment: I found something like Node.js, but I have to figure out and I think this is what I was searching.

Comment: Node.js includes a small web server.  It would definitely be a decent fit if you feel comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make your AJAX calls to static HTML files.

Comment: You need to call the same server that's hosting the original page.

Comment: *IF* the response in JSON, not HTML.